# GCP: can one VM be on different networks with the same address?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, vpc

Question related to GCP (Google Cloud Platform):
can one VM be in different networks with one address?
I work with cloud providers (AWS, GCP, Azure) and use libraries for java (aws.sdk, azure.sdk, google.sdk).
In short: virtual machines are created in my application. Also, additional software is installed on these virtual machines.
This software runs on the same network.
I want to realize that this software can work in different networks.

For example, a security group (rules) is created for Azure.
Azure, like AWS, does not allow you to connect network interfaces from different VPCs to the same virtual machine instance.
To implement this approach, I had to create an additional security group using the azure.sdk library and the **NetworkSecurityGroupInner** class.

Nowhere can I find something similar for java for GCP.
Can you share some examples or interesting links or articles? I'll be very grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "one VM be in different networks with one address?".  For me, there are a few interpretations of that.

Comment: Keep in mind that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic on SO.  However if you clarify the question this might be answerable without a recommendation.

Comment: WHat is `network` for you? a VPC? a subnet? Of which IP address are you talking about? Private? Public?

Comment: @Kolban 
maybe I put it non-verbally, I mean: One VM is on different networks. Those. one VM machine has 2 network interfaces from different VPCs, one has a public address and the second is a static address.

Comment: @Kolban For example, for Amazon:
AWS does not allow you to connect network interfaces from different VPCs for a single instance of EC2. There are two ways to establish communication between some instances from different VPCs:
1) peering VPC
2) AWS Transit Gateway

Comment: @Kolban I read the documentation about Google and did not find such information that Google also does not have the ability to connect network interfaces from different VPCs for one instance. But also did not find anywhere information on how to do this and whether it has such a feature by default.

Comment: @robsiemb I added information in the comments. thanks

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I added information in the comments. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can one VM be in different networks with one address? the answer is yes. BUT you have to set two way network peering as this diagram:

[image: From qwiklabs.com]

Learn more about network peering:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering

for quick tutorial to get this see this good hands-on lab
https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/964?catalog_rank=%7B%22rank%22%3A6%2C%22num_filters%22%3A0%2C%22has_search%22%3Atrue%7D&parent=catalog&search_id=3929793